# What is the best Web Development IDE for OS X (that is comparable to Visual Studio)?

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio, xcode, web-development

I'm trying to find a good Web Development IDE for OS X Yosemite. And I've just run out of things to search for, so now I'm asking you - do you know of any that compare to Visual Studio on Windows?

---

- Specifically, I'm looking for a native application (natively-built, that is - not some Java-based crap or a web app disguised as a normal app);
- Code Completion, (very similar, if not the same as Intellisense in Visual Studio);
- Lots and lots of features! Build features, debug features, breakpoints, refactoring, unit testing (optional);
- Multiple language support - and preferably .NET-based language support, too (if you're going to suggest Mono or MonoDevelop, please also suggest an alternative to that).

Syntax highlighting is of least importance to me at this point. I am really struggling to find a descent IDE for OS X.

Ideally this IDE would have support for C# (a must), Ruby on Rails, PHP (a must), and (probably wishful thinking) some kind of support for Windows Azure deployment.

---

I have tried many IDE's on OS X - including PHPStorm and Web Storm however I can't even get those to work, despite having installed all dependencies.

_Also, if anybody knows how to use Xcode 6.X for Web Development (in any language), that would just make my day.

Comment: Try [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search gets [this result](http://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/):

> August 2014: I streamlined this tutorial to make it even easier to set
>   up your development environment. I’ve archived the original version.
>   This version works with OS X Yosemite (10.10), or Mavericks (10.9) and
>   uses Homebrew instead of MacPorts as a package manager.

- Why Not Just Use MAMP?

MAMP is a package that will install MySQL, PHP, and Apache on your Mac all with one download, and a quick install ...

- Xcode

First, you need to have Xcode (Apple’s development bundle) installed for a few of these tools to work. You can get by without it if you try really hard, but if you’re a developer, you’re probably going to need to have it at some point. It’s massive, so start downloading it now. Grab it from the App Store, and then grab a coffee or play with your kid or dog ...

... and so long.

Take a look!

Comment: I am interested to know which keywords you used when searching for this. I spent two days searching Google.

Comment: I have copied it from your title: "Web Development IDE for OS X" https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=+Web+Development+IDE+for+OS+X+ :)